# Linker errors with libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0 preventing pyODBC to MS SQL connection. CentOS 7

Tags: python, sql, linux, centos, odbc

I am trying to connect from a python app with pyodbc to a MS SQL server. I have pyodbc and unixODBC installed and I tried to install the MS driver for linux. I think the issue is that the MS driver has missing dependencies but as near as I can tell the dependencies are installed. Because the Microsoft driver was not install-able through yum i had to wget and run the install script. So there Im sure there is some manual work I have to do to get the links missing below to resolve. I am not sure how to do this as I am new to this on Linux. I have included my config files also just in case.

When I run...

```
 ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0
```

I get the following...

```
/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0)

/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0)

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff22b27000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f03de43f000)
libodbcinst.so.2 => /lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f03de22d000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f03de027000)
libgss.so.3 => not found
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f03ddd42000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f03dda39000)
....(THE REST ARE FOUND)
```

[image: odbcinst.ini]
[image: odbc.ini]

Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thank You!

Comment: your screen shots are unreadable. Can't you just copy/paste the error messages into  your Q as you have done with `ldd` output. Good luc,.

Comment: I think you're working with an incompatible version of unixODBC for msodbcsql. Check that the command ```odbc_config --version``` return the expected version for msodbcsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember I had this issue too but it was more than one year ago and I don't have access to that server anymore.

As far as I can remember it was a version mismatch. If you see your `ldd` output they're looking for libgss.so.3, libcrypto.so.1.0.0, etc. Maybe you have different version of these library installed on your system.

By looking my installation notes it looks like I fixed the issue by creating (soft) links "pointing" the libraries I had on my system. And - of course - I gave these links the names msodbc was looking for. Yes... a little bit "rude" but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. This is the direction I was headed. Quick question. Do I create the soft link in the location where the binary is looking for the file? So in my case does it go in /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 and redirect to wherever the actual version is? Any possibility of a sample ln -s command to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't create soft links under /lib or /usr/lib on that server (security restrictions and I didn't have root password). So... I created these soft links in a directory under my home-dir (`${HOME}/mslib/`) and added this directory to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH...

Comment: Sample command: `mkdir $HOME/mslib` and then `ln -s /usr/lib/libgss-3.0.0 $HOME/mslib/libgss-2.8.0` (I don't remember version number - I just wrote random numbers here). Finally put your new LIB directory **before** the others: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/mslib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`